# Cron job not running for a specific user for nodejs

Tags: bash, permissions, cron

I installed nodejs for my specific user. I implemented a price feeder application and when I do a `whereis feeder` I get the following output:

```
feeder: /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/feeder
```

I am then trying to run a cronjob to execute that every hour and created a cronjob with `crontab -e` when I was logged in with the username of user like in my directory path with the following job:

```
33 * * * * /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/feeder nodename priv_key
```

For some reason, I must not have the right level of access because this doesn't broadcast the transaction (this is a blockchain node so when I say broadcast I mean shows up in the blockchain). I know it works because there is a test function you can run which broadcasts the transaction successfully so I think it's a cronjob access issue.

I tried to view the output with the following command `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` but get the following error: `grep: /var/log/syslog: Permission denied`

Here is the output for the syslog when my job ran based on running `sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog` as suggested in the commends:

```
Jan  6 12:33:01 server CRON[14787]: (user) CMD (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/feeder nodename priv_key)
Jan  6 12:33:01 server CRON[14786]: (user) MAIL (mailed 52 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
```

Anyone know why my cronjob couldn't access this or have the right permissions?

EDIT: I updated the cronjob based on the comments and here is the output of the error file `/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`

`type node` returns:

```
node is /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means that something you are trying to run is a script which most likely has the following [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Essentially, this means "find the first executable file called `env` in this user's $PATH". The `PATH` variable holds the list of directories that contain executables. The problem is that cron has its own environment, and therefore [its own `PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401621/22222), and that does not include the directory where the `node` command is. So you need to edit your crontab file and change it like this:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin"
33 * * * * /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/feeder nodename priv_key
```

Make sure you add the *directory* and not the file. So if your `node` is `/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node`, you need:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin"
```

and not:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node"
```

Then, save the crontab and you should be fine. If your un into similar problems, repeat the procedure: redirect the stderr and stdout to a file by apending `> /tmp/somefile 2>&1` to the end of the cron command, check the error message and add the directory containing whatever else it needs to the path in a similar way:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/path/to/node:/some/other/path"
```